# Some text display on my terminal

Tags: command-line, 16.04

when I open my terminal following text display on it.

```
bash: alias: -o: not found
bash: alias: allow_other: not found
bash: alias: /media/GalaxyS: not found
bash: alias: -u: not found
bash: alias: /media/GalaxyS: not found
```

I use Ubuntu 16.04. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please correct the errors in your `/home/your_username/.bashrc` file look at the __lines with alias__ they are errors there.

Comment: You have an error in your .bashrc, .bash_aliases or .profile file. Have you tried to create an alias recently ?

Comment: @SorenA  I try to install mtpfs. following this (https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-connect-your-android-device-on-linux/) .

Comment: As @George wrote above, look for lines with alias in .bashrc or the otther files I mentioned, and fix the error ..

Comment: @SorenA Thank you. Your solution is working for me.

Answer (score -1):

There are errors in `.bashrc` (or `.bash_aliases` or `.profile`) in your home directory. Find the line(s) containing 'alias' and correct the error.

Comment: To write a [good answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer) you could explain **where** those files are, **how** to find such lines and **how** to edit the files.